# R: How can I simulate first uncorrelated variables and them "correlate" them?

Tags: r, simulation, correlation

assume, that I want to do two simulations with three variables. In the first simulation (lets call it sima) I want to generate three uniform or normal distributed variables, that are uncorrelated. Then I want to to some analysis stuff.
After that I want to repeat the analysis, but I want now, that my generated variables from the first simulation (sima) are correlated:

I know, that I can use the mvrnorm function, but I've no idea, how to "correlate" my generated data from the first simulation

For example

```
a <- rnorm(1000)
b <- rnorm(1000)
c <- rnorm(1000)

x <- matrix(c(a,b,c), ncol=3)
```

Then I want to correlate the matrix x with for example correlations of:

```
cor(a,b)=0.4

cor(a,c)=0.3

cor(b,c)=0.5
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to take the raw data of `a`-`c` – don't use `c` as a variable name BTW – and arrange them so they are correlated? I.e. the numbers have to be unchanged? Or do you just want some standard normal variables that are correlated?

Comment: Thats the point. I want first to use the uncorrelated data for a simulation. And then correlate the same numbers, so they should be unchanged, to do the same simuation study with correlations

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can use the function `MASS::mvrnorm`

```
samples <- 200
rab <- 0.4
rac <- 0.3
rbc <- 0.5

data <-  MASS::mvrnorm(n=samples,
                     mu=c(0, 0, 0),
                     Sigma=matrix(c(1, rab, rac,
                                    rab, 1, rbc, 
                                    rac, rbc, 1),
                                  nrow=3),
                     empirical=TRUE)
A <- data[, 1]  
B <- data[, 2] 
C <- data[, 3]

cor(data)
cor(A, B)
cor(A, C)
cor(B, C)


> cor(data)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.4  0.3
[2,]  0.4  1.0  0.5
[3,]  0.3  0.5  1.0
> cor(A, B)
[1] 0.4
> cor(A, C)
[1] 0.3
> cor(B, C)
[1] 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch it around. First create the correlated data as in DJV's post above. Then decorrelate it by randomly shuffling. This doesn't guarantee you precisely zero correlation in the sample - but that's also true for independently sampled data.

```
# first create `data` as in DJV's post. Then:

data_indep <- apply(data, 2, sample)
cor(data2)
            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,]  1.00000000  0.07503708 -0.13515778
[2,]  0.07503708  1.00000000 -0.02912137
[3,] -0.13515778 -0.02912137  1.00000000
```

To show that on average, the reshuffled data is uncorrelated (which is analytically true, but let's check):

```
replicate(10000, {data2 <- apply(data, 2, sample); cor(data2)}) -> cors
apply(cors, 1:2, mean)
              [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
[1,]  1.0000000000 -0.0009533055 0.0014867635
[2,] -0.0009533055  1.0000000000 0.0002847576
[3,]  0.0014867635  0.0002847576 1.0000000000
```

Good enough, I think.